# flexbox, flex-end in IE10

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Quite a straight forward question, I think. I'm trying to align a div to the bottom of it's container, should this work in IE10 using flexbox?

I have 2 div's within a parent div which are displayed side-by-side, one shorter in height than the other. This is the CSS I'm using which works in IE11...

```
.col-parent {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.col {
    -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
    -moz-align-self: flex-end;
    -ms-align-self: flex-end;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

I thought would be enough? I've also considered using the following on the parent div instead:

```
.col-parent {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: flex-end;
    -moz-box-align: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-align: flex-end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Which I'm sure when I tested didn't work in IE10, again. If it doesn't work thats fine with me. I just don't want to leave it if flexbox should be working in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE10 supports the 2012 syntax, therefor try "end" as the value..

Also see: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Is that for `-ms-flex-align: end` (on the parent), rather than `-ms-flex-align: end` (on the child)?

Comment: this answer very helpful, does anyone know how to actually write this so ie understands it?